# Angular material table - styles lost when changing page with paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I have a problem with the angular material table. I've added mat-form-field and mat input as table cells, `ng-model` to track values and different styles when editing inputs where I'm setting the background color to red when `ng-dirty` is present. The problem is with pagination, whenever I move to the next page and return to the previous one where something was edited, styles are lost.

I somehow need to preserve `ng-dirty` on edited fields even though I'm changing pages with `paginator`.

[Stackblitz with code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3zkmx?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

- Add a new property to `PeriodicElement` like `originalWeight?:number;` and in the `PeriodicElement` list just duplicate the values for each item like this `{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', originalWeight:1.0079, weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},`
- Add in the styles another class:

> input.ng-dirty, input.ng-dirty-back{
> background-color: red;
> }

- in the HTML just do:

> <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.weight" [class]="element.originalWeight!= undefined && element.weight != element.originalWeight ? 'ng-dirty-back':''" />

Comment: Great, thanks. Works fine for this question. And if I want to set mat-form-field-flex border style for this input field also?

Comment: U can mark the answer as a valid solution in this case :).

Comment: Sorry, marked :)